# Как изменить размер tableView в контроллере?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile-development

Создаю NavigationController в сториборде
[image: NavigationController]

в итоге получаю на выходе примерно такой список, для примера
[image: Список]

Создаю дополнительную вьюшку в нижней части экрана с информацией о выбранных пунктах, она ложится поверх таблицы и соответственно перекрывает нижние ячейки. Как можно изменить размер самой таблицы, чтобы она заканчивалась там где начинается моя вьюха?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно удалить TableViewController и создать простой UIViewController, на него положить UITableView и изменять размер, как захочешь.

Также есть такая функция setContentSize, там можешь изменить размер примерно таким образом:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView;
frame.size.height -= view.frame.size.height;

[self.tableView setContentSize:frame]
```

Comment: setContentSize почему-то ничего не менял, поэтому пошел первым путем, заодно разобрался как устроен TableViewController